# how Multi query dbase/dbf with library.net IN VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dbf, dbase

I want to do multi query with dbase/dbf database with .net library.

I don't want to use oledb because my record is three hundred thousand and I want the data table in datagridview.
I need a fast library please recommend?
Thanks
roy

```
Imports DbfDataReader
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1
    Dim dbfPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\IFG.DBF"
    Dim options = New DbfDataReaderOptions With {
     .SkipDeletedRecords = True,
     .Encoding = EncodingProvider.UTF8
    }



End Class
```

Comment: Are you trying to display 300,000 records? I think that is more than any user would want to see.

Comment: Sorry I'm late in replying, Yes that's right I want to display 300,000 records in datagirdview.

Comment: Have you installed a Nuget package to read dbf? Browse that available packages. One of these will work with ADO.net

Comment: Dear mr.nary, I haven't installed the nuget package to read the dbf file and I want it via a third party library and please recommend me which library should I use

Comment: I do not use dbase so I cannot recommend but it appears the most popular DbfDataReader with 150,000 downloads.

Comment: dear mr.mary,
can you provide me the code in vb.net with dbfdatareader library

Comment: Go to the Nuget manager on the Tools menu and choose to add to your project.

Comment: dear mr.mary ,
I will try

Comment: dear mr.mary, I have a new post question, can you help me

Comment: If you want to read ALL records of your table, you may also consider to write your own, specific bulk loader for that amount. DBF format (no matter what flavour) are not that complex to decode.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor do you mean I made a standard code from me?

Comment: @roy: What do you mean with "standard code"? I mean you can also write your own DBF reader, optimized for your table structure (read the whole thing in a byte array and handle the splitting into records / fields by your own code).

Comment: @Mary , I've tried using the dbfdatareader library and have also made the code but I'm still confused about displaying it in the datagridview

Comment: @nabuchodonossor ,I've tried using the dbfdatareader library and have also made the code but I'm still confused about displaying it in the datagridview

Comment: @roy: I do not know the dbfdatareader, but you have to add rows to the datagridview for each row in your source data. I assume you try to "databind" it, mabye the reader cannot not this. Later this day I can try the dbfdatareader.

Comment: @roy: As far as I can see now, you have to read all records, extract the single fields and add a row to your datagrid (what would be more efficient, create a bindingsource and do the binding in the end). There are samples on the project page for reading records.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor , please give an example of using the dbfdatareader library and showing it in datagridview

Comment: when you go to the link on the project page you will find a very easy to follow example. You have just to try. Then, if you stuck, we here on SO might be able to help you. But not without efforts on your side.